# Live Analytic Data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, node.js, analytics

I'm planning on creating a live analytics's page for my website - A bit like Google Analytic but will real live data which will change as new users load a page on my site etc.

The main site is/will be written using Asp.Net/C# as the back end with a MS SQL database and the front end will support things like **JavaScript** (JQuery), **CSS3**, **HTML5** (If required).

I was wondering what methods can I use to have the live analytic in terms of; How to get the data onto the analytic's page, what **efficient graphing** can I use, and storing the data with **fast input/output.**

The first thing that came to my mind is to use **Node.js** - Could I use this to achieve a live analytic's page? Is a good idea? Are there any better alternatives? Any drawbacks with this?

Would I need a **C#** Application running on a server to use Node.js to send/receive all the data to and from the website?

Would using a **MS SQL** database be fast enough? Would I need to store all the data live, or could I store it in chunks every x amount of seconds/minutes? (Which would be more efficient?)

This illustrates my initial thoughts on the matter - 
[image: Flow Diagram Of Live Analytic's]

**Edit:**

I'm going to be using this system over multiple sites, I could be getting 10 hits at a time to around 1,000,000 (Highly unlikely, but still possible). I want to be able to scale this system and adapt it to the environment it's in.

Comment: Most of this seems like it would depend on what kind of traffic you have.  Do you currently know how many views-per-day you have and whatnot?

Comment: Not yet, the sited isn't created yet. But it could vary from 10 a day to 1,000,000 - I'm planning on using this system across multiple sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on how "real time" the realtime data needs to be. For example, I made this recently:

http://www.reed.co.uk/labs/realtime/

Which shows job applications coming into the system. Obviously there is way too much going on during busy periods to actually be querying the main database in realtime - so, what we do is query a sliding "window" and cache it on the server - this is a chunk of the last 5minutes worth of events.

We then play this back to the user as is it's happening "now". having a little latency as part of a SLA (wherein the users don't really care) can make the whole system vastly more scalable.

[EDIT- further explanation]

The data is just retrieved from a basic stored procedure call - naturally, a big system like reed has hundreds of transactions/second - so we cant keep hitting the main cluster, for every user.

All we do, is make sure we have a current window, in this case the last 5min of data cached on the server. When a client comes to the site, we get that last 5min of data, and play it back like it's happening right now - the end user is none-the-wiser - but what it means is that all clients are reading off the cache. Once the cache is 5min old, we invalidate it, and start again. This means a max of 1 DB hit, every five min - thus making teh system vastly more scalable (not that it really needs to be - as it's just for fun, really)

Comment: I love that system you've made, exactly the sort of thing I want/need. Could you expand more on how you achieved this? The technology behind it etc? What would the lowest window of time could this be done in? 5 minutes seems a little too long for my site. 

Ps. What mapping system do you use for that site?

Comment: Excellent, that's all handy dandy and what not. But How does the website get the data exactly? Is it as simple as get all the data for the 5 minutes at once, store it in memory and then over the 5 minute period it shows the blips evenly and then discards the data and get the next 5 minutes?

 Sorry for all the question - Just want to make sure I have a firm grasp on the matter :) Thank you for all of your help so far.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your help, much appreciated :) (Is that Google Maps you're using on the reed site?)

Answer (score 0):

Just so you are aware Google analytics's already offers live user tracking. when inside the dashboard of a site on Google analytics's. click the home button on the top bar, and then the real time button on the left bar. Considering the design work and quality of this service, it seems this may be a better option then to attempt to recreate its service. If you do choose to proceed to create your own, then you can at least use their services as a benchmark for the desired features.

Using Api's like the googles charting API https://developers.google.com/chart/ would be a good approach to displaying the output of your stored data, with decreased development time. If you provide more information on the number of hits you exspect, and the scale of the server this software will be hosted, then it will be easier to give you answers to the speed questions.